# Does DataAdapter use facade pattern or Adapter pattern.

Tags: design-patterns, dataadapter, facade

When I see `Update()`, `Fill()` methods of `DataAdapter` object, I always think whether `DataAdapter` uses Facade Pattern?

It looks like behind the scenes it will create `Command` object, `Connection` object and execute it for us.

Or `DataAdapter` uses Adapter Pattern because it is adapter between `Dataset` and `Command` object, Connection object?

Answer (score 3):

Not everything is a GoF design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could perhaps think of it like the Repository pattern, just that it focuses on data connections. Its not really an adapter because its not facilitating a communication mechanism between command and dataset - its actually manipulating and creating its own commands for its own purposes.